# Counting linked list nodes using Recursion

Tags: c#, recursion

How can I count the number of single linked list nodes using recursion (no while or for loops only if statements)

```
int Elements(Node head)
{
    if (head==null)
        return 0;
    else
    {

    }
    head=head.next;
}
```

Comment: Where is the recursion in your code?

Comment: [Recursion on Linked Lists](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-21/lectures/llrecursion/lecture.html)

Answer (score 6):

```
int Elements(Node head)
{
    if (head==null)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1 + Elements(head.next);
}
```

Comment: Bold, Elegant, i like it.

Comment: I LOVEEE IT. Thank you. I am having difficulty getting my head "wrapped" around recursion. Do you have any tips on how to imagine or think about it?

Comment: Think of yourself thinking of yourself thinking of yourself thinking of yourself thinking of recursion. But seriously, recursion is about finding a pattern in a problem, and stating that problem in terms of that pattern. "If knew the answer to a(n-1), then I would know the answer to a(n)."

Comment: Think of it as dropping the number one down on the ground as you visit each node, then jumping to the next node and repeating.  When you reach the last node and have nowhere to go, you follow the breadcrumb trail back to the beginning and add up all the ones as you pick them up, thus arriving at your answer.